# Using jQuery with JSON and Google Spreadsheets Data API

Tags: jquery, json, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to get a JSON string using the Google Spreadsheets Data API. I'm trying to start out easy, just have an alert box pop up after the JSON string is successfully loaded.

```
$(function(){
  var json_uri = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AvC4NUSdTIgddFJnUFRkcnI0QkJDLVg2eklZd0FZVVE/od6/public/values?alt=json";
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: json_uri,
    success: function(data){
      alert("success");
    }
  });
});
```

But I never see the alert box. What's happening? I'm new to both JSON and the Spreadsheets API, so hopefully this is just some simple thing I'm overlooking.

Google's sample page: http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample.html

My jsbin example page: http://jsbin.com/otuxiv/11

Comment: your test page shows an alert box to me in FF.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome as well.

Comment: On IE, if you debug the JavaScript, it fails with "Access Denied" error. The XMLHttpRequest object used to do the ajax call, does not allow https calls from non http pages, you might want to focus your research on that path... it works however on FF, Chrome and Safari!!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It did work on Chrome for me, but that was it. It didn't work on IE7/8, FF7, Opera 11, or Safari 4 for me. I'll look into the https calls next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd set a dataType for the ajax call to dataType: 'jsonp', and also try changing

```
var json_uri = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AvC4NUSdTIgddFJnUFRkcnI0QkJDLVg2eklZd0FZVVE/od6/public/values?alt=json";
```

to

```
var json_uri = "//spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AvC4NUSdTIgddFJnUFRkcnI0QkJDLVg2eklZd0FZVVE/od6/public/values?alt=json";
```

Haven't had time to test but might get you past the IE error.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work for me. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: When I try this, I only get "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1Hj9HCBaTgZPjgoEhnLG8UXKUnsyJUjHLSvxxk_U4OTk/od6/public/values?alt=json. Received an invalid response. Origin 'http://svenhenrikkarlsson.com' is therefore not allowed access. " Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your first example worked for me in Firefox 15.01

You could save a lot of trouble parsing that huge JSON object if you moved your data to a service like jsondata.com.

All around, the Google Spreadsheets API is cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution here is to use this https://gist.github.com/ronaldsmartin/47f5239ab1834c47088e to wrap around your existing spreadsheet.

Add the `id` and `sheet` html param to the URL below.

> https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzGvKKUIaqsMuCj7-A2YRhR-f7GZjl4kSxSN1YyLkS01_CfiyE/exec

Eg: your `id` is your sheet id which is

`0AvC4NUSdTIgddFJnUFRkcnI0QkJDLVg2eklZd0FZVVE`

and your sheet which is

`Sheet1`

In your case you can actually see your data (it's actually working) here as json at

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzGvKKUIaqsMuCj7-A2YRhR-f7GZjl4kSxSN1YyLkS01_CfiyE/exec?id=0AvC4NUSdTIgddFJnUFRkcnI0QkJDLVg2eklZd0FZVVE&sheet=Sheet1

To be safe, you should deploy the code `sheetAsJson.gs` in the github gist above as your own in your Google Drive.